# ¿Como tomar un valor de un Json dentro de otro Json en android studio?

Tags: android-studio, json

la verdad soy un poco nuevo en el tema de las apps, entonces estoy haciendo una, la app conecta con un webservice que me devuele un Json y tomo los valores de ese Json y los muestro dentro de la app, el código de ese webService es el siguiente:

```
 class app_android_residuos_rv extends Controller
 {


public function busqueda()
{
    $success = false;
    $message = "";
    $caja = "";

    if($recepcionResiduosRevalorizables = recepcionResiduosRevalorizables::all()){
        $success = true;
        $message = "Documentos cargados correctamente";
    } else {
        $success = false;
        $message = "Error al cargar los datos";
    }
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($recepcionResiduosRevalorizables); $i++) {
        $recepcionResiduosRevalorizables[$i]->caja;
    }

   return response()->json([
    'data'   =>  $recepcionResiduosRevalorizables,
    'success' => $success,
    'message' => $message
   ]);
}
```

Ese webservice me devuelve el siguiente Json:

> {"data":[{"id":88,"carton":"66.00","emplaye":"45.00","observaciones":"chsvito","fecha_hora_captura":"2020-10-12 11:17:16","numero_pallets":66,"caja_id":840,"caja":{"id":840,"numero":"35"}},{"id":99,"carton":"22.00","emplaye":"66.00","observaciones":"resentido","fecha_hora_captura":"2020-10-13 15:19:52","numero_pallets":65,"caja_id":816,"caja":{"id":816,"numero":"1"}}],"success":true,"message":"Documentos cargados correctamente"}

Como podrán notar dentro del Json tengo otro con el nombre "caja" y dentro del Json "caja" tengo los valores: "id" y "número"

El código de mi aplicación para consumirlo es el siguiente:

```
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, Constants.URL_SELECT, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            try{

                progressDialog.hide();
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");

                Toast.makeText(ListActivity.this,jsonObject.getString("message"),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                for (int i = 0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++){
                    JSONObject o = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    Model item = new Model(
                            o.getString("id"),
                            o.getString("carton"),
                            o.getString("emplaye"),
                            o.getString("observaciones"),
                            o.getString("numero_pallets"),
                            o.getString("fecha_hora_captura"),
                            o.getString("caja")
                    );
                    listItems.add(item);

                    adapter = new MyAdapter(listItems,getApplicationContext());
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

                }
            }catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            progressDialog.hide();
            Toast.makeText(ListActivity.this, "ERROR",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }){
        protected Map<String , String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String , String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("id", "kl");
            return params;
        }
    };
    RequestHandler.getInstance(ListActivity.this).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);
}
```

Hasta aquí todo bien, el código me trae los valores tal cual los necesito, el problema esta en la linea que dice :

```
  o.getString("caja")
```

Ya que este me trae como valor el Json "caja" ejemplo, me muestra el siguiente valor:

```
 "caja":{"id":816,"numero":"1"}
```

Cuando yo necesito únicamente el valor de "numero" dentro de "caja" y no se como invocarlo, he investigado, e incluso trate de hacerlo como se haría en una vista de laravel, pero nada me sale, agradecería su ayuda.

Añado imagén de como se ve:
[image: IMAGEN]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De acuerdo a la estructura de tu json, el elemento "caja" es un objeto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

por lo tanto si deseas obtener un valor dentro del objeto "caja", simplemente crea un `JSONObject` y obtén su valor de "numero":

```
new JSONObject(o.getString("caja")).getString("numero")
```

Este sería el código :

```
                Model item = new Model(
                        o.getString("id"),
                        o.getString("carton"),
                        o.getString("emplaye"),
                        o.getString("observaciones"),
                        o.getString("numero_pallets"),
                        o.getString("fecha_hora_captura"),
                        new JSONObject(o.getString("caja")).getString("numero")
                );
```

Comment: Quedo perfecto amigo, al final la linea quedo así:
 numeroCaja = String.valueOf(new JSONObject(o.getString("caja")).getString("numero"))
tomando en cuenta que numeroCaja es un String.

Comment: Excelente @alexvargas6 , saludos!